# What is the point of the zero ohm resistor between LED_VCC and VCC_3V3?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, noise

I am designing a IR sensor transimpedance amplifier circuit based off of the Texas Instruments Particle Sensor (TIDA-00378). Between the separate power buses (LED,TIA,VCC) there is a connection with a zero ohm resistor. Am I supposed to put a ferrite bead there to reduce some sort of noise? Or is it just to act as a jumper if I want to use separate power supplies? Thanks!

[image: TIDA-00378]

Comment: for testing. its easy to open-circuit and use the pads to put a current meter in series

Comment: 2nd reason: If this is a demo board for something that might need to be very low power or battery operated in the final version, you can remove these resistors to not waste power on the LEDs once you're confident you don't need the visual indicator.

Comment: And, finally, some people like to use zero-ohm resistors like that to insure that power planes are only connected in one well-controlled spot.  But I suspect that the first reason is for versatility in hacking the board, and the second is measurement.

Comment: So, looking at the schematic snippet there -- just how much current to hit 1/4W in a **zero** ohm resistor? :)

Comment: if you can find me one that's within 5% tolerance I'll measure it :)